# Kafka streams stuck on consuming shortly after application starts

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using both **Kafka** and **Kafka Streams** in my Spring application. While regular **Kafka** communication such as sending/receiving to/from topics is working fine, **Kafka Streams** stop consuming(processing records) shortly after application starts. The strange thing is that when I restart the application, the processing of records resumes for a short time, and even some processed data is sent to topic, but shortly after **Kafka Streams** get stuck again.
I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something, probably Kafka Streams are not configured in a right way or maybe I'm consuming in a wrong way.

**Broker configuration:**
I've got cluster of 3 brokers, in general I'm using the default Kafka broker configuration that comes with the binaries, except that I raised the number of partitions per topic to **3**.

Only configs I've changed(also due to cluster size as recommended):

```
num.partitions=3
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
```

**Versions and OS:**
I'm using **Kafka Streams v2.1.0**, **Kafka clients v2.1.0**, **Kafka brokers v2.1.0** and **Spring Kafka 2.2.3.RELEASE**.

Brokers and consumers running on **Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)**.

**Kafka Streams java configuration:**

```
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, STREAMS_ID);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 15);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, StreamExceptionHandler.class);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
```

I've got 15 Stream Threads for optimal concurrency using the following logic:
**#num_of_partitions * #num_of_stream_topics**

**Example of what a Kafka Streams consumer does:**

```
    KStream<String, ActivityLog> kStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(ServerConstants.KAFKA.ACTIVITY_LOGS_DESTINATION_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), getActivityLogSerde()));

    TriggerSensitivities triggerSensitivities = PredefinedTriggerSensitivities.SOME_TRIGGER;

    kStream
            .filter((id, activityLog) ->
                    isValidRecord(id, activityLog) &&
                            SUPPORTED_EVENT_TYPES.contains(activityLog.getType())
                            && ruleService.hasRuleForActivity(id, activityLog, ThreatTrigger.TYPE.SOME_TRIGGER))

            .selectKey((id, activityLog) -> new SelectedKey(id, activityLog.getEmail(),
                    ThreatTrigger.TYPE.SOME_TRIGGER, activityLog.getName()).toString())
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.of(triggerSensitivities.getHighestTimePeriod(), ChronoUnit.MILLIS)))
            .aggregate(ArrayList<ActivityLog>::new,
                    (selectedKey, activityLog, activityLogs) -> {
                        activityLogs.add(activityLog);
                        return activityLogs;
                    },
                    Materialized.with(Serdes.String(),
                            Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonPOJOSerializer<>(), new JsonPOJODeserializer<>(ArrayList.class, ActivityLog.class))))
            .toStream()
            .selectKey((windowedKey, activityLogs) -> windowedKey.key())
            .mapValues((selectedKey, activityLogs) ->
                    ruleService.getMatchedTriggerActivities(triggerSensitivities,
                            ThreatTrigger.TYPE.SOME_TRIGGER,
                            selectedKey,
                            activityLogs))
            .to(ServerConstants.KAFKA.DETECTION_EVENTS_TOPIC);
```

**What I tried to achieve here is the following:**
I'm receiving different activity logs, filtering them by various criteria, then aggregating them according to a certain key over a certain amount of time and if I aggregated enough of them + some extra logic I'm generating an event.  It works at first as expected and then hangs.

**Broker logs:**
Bunch of **INFO** logs, that look pretty much the same to me

```
[2019-02-26 22:25:13,502] INFO [Log partition=coronet-streams-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000200-repartition-1, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Incrementing log start offset to 3467 (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-26 22:25:55,241] INFO [Log partition=coronet-streams-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000200-repartition-1, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Incrementing log start offset to 3470 (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-26 22:26:31,133] INFO [Log partition=coronet-streams-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000200-repartition-1, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Incrementing log start offset to 3471 (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-26 22:27:07,845] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=coronet-streams-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000292-repartition-1] Writing producer snapshot at offset 2127 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2019-02-26 22:27:07,845] INFO [Log partition=coronet-streams-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000292-repartition-1, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Rolled new log segment at offset 2127 in 1 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-26 22:34:32,835] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

**Consumer logs:**
Sometimes the following log is printed, but I found later on several sources that this **WARN** does not impact processing.

```
2019-02-26 22:44:19.291  WARN 7350 --- [coronet-streams-6553b7a0-b6fb-4e07-ad16-c040374e201e-StreamThread-4] o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager        : task [0
_0] Failed to write offset checkpoint file to /tmp/kafka-streams/coronet-streams/0_0/.checkpoint: {}

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka-streams/coronet-streams/0_0/.checkpoint.tmp (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.OffsetCheckpoint.write(OffsetCheckpoint.java:79)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.checkpoint(ProcessorStateManager.java:293)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:446)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:431)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:346)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:405)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:1029)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:883)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

Except from that I **DO SEE** some logs printed here and there by stream threads using the application logger, so it seems that the streams are sometimes working(with some long delays), but are mostly stuck some why!

It would help a-lot if someone could point what could be a problem!
Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say. However, you should definitely change you broker and streams config to not use `/tmp/` -- this can result in issues. When you say the application is "stuck" how to you observe this? The application starts to lag? If yes, you might want to increase log level to DEBUG to see if the application send fetch requests successfully and gets data from the brokers.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I just see that records either processed with long delays or not processed at all. I'll try to change consumer log level to DEBUG. I'll try as well to change streams dir. Thanks.

Comment: Any solution you get ?

Comment: @Evgeny, have you found a reason of the issue?